# C# WPF update GUI and move grid

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, invoke, dispatcher

I am creating a simple application in WPF that changes the position of a grid programmatically.

The main aim is clicking on a button and a grid will start moving to left,right,up,down,etc..

So i have wrote this code :

```
    Grid G = new Grid();

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread tt = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { RUN(); });

        }); tt.Start();
    }

    private void RUN()
    {
        G.Margin = new Thickness(0, MAIN_GRID.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
        G.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        G.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

        MAIN_GRID.Children.Add(G);

        while (G.Margin.Top > 0)
        {
            G.Margin = new Thickness(0, G.Margin.Top - 1, 0, 0);

            MAIN_GRID.InvalidateVisual(); // tried refreshing the GUI but no good...

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

What happens is that it does exactly what i need but without showing me the animation.

For example my code should move the grid up by 1 pixel then sleep for 10 milliseconds and that is enough to see the grid actually moving.

But instead it freezes and once it is done it shows me the final position of the grid.

I did that in windows applications using threading only and it works fine. But i needed to do that in WPF because i needed it to be smoother.

Comment: @GrantWinney I was actually using Threading in windows forms.

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks a lot man, i fixed it, all i had to do is just putting the new position on a separate function that is being invoked each time instead of one time only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'while' loop is locking the UI thread and preventing the incremental changes from appearing.  Two alternatives are [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx) wrap the body of your loop into a method that gets invoked by the Dispatcher (and thus free up the UI thread to update the user surface).

Or [2] create a Storyboard dynamically that uses DoubleAnimation on the Margin Top.  Using [2] would require you to pre-measure the amount of movement, but might be worth it if you wanted to add an impressive easing function when the grid neared its final destination.

[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx) is the quickest to implement, [2] allows for a slick visual effect.  [msdn docs are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx)

Comment: i couldn't figure out what you mean.

can you provide me with code sample please?

Comment: @BOSS if the concept of Storyboards is new, you might look at the overview first in order to get the concept.  Once you have the theory of how WPF uses them, they are very straight-forward.  But if you wanted to jump straight to the code, there's a great sample on MSDN.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754066.aspx  They are animating a property in precisely the way you need.  In the sample, it's the width property and in your case it's the margin top property.  About 8 or 9 lines of code is what you need...

Comment: Wow that's awesome, i am going to take a look and figure it out.

Thanks a lot for that awesome resource.

Comment: @BOSS, any problems along the way, just open a question about WPF Storyboards.  They are fun!